# Finding the minimum of $f(x,y)$ by simple inspection

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}+ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2-2x+1}+\sqrt{x^2 + y^2-2y+1}+\sqrt{x^2 + y^2-6x-8y +25}$$

Find minimum value of $f$.

Now, We see that we can complete the squares, but how do we proceed after that? Is there any general technique for such problems?

Comment: There is no simple technique to find the answer. The answer is somewhere in $(x,y)\in(0.4,0.5)\times(0.5,0.6)$ but I got that by graphing with the computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $d:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $ ((a,b),(c,d))\longmapsto\sqrt{(a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2} $ then  $d((a,b),(c,d)) $ means the distance between $(a,b),(c,d)$. So, we can change $f(x,y)$ to the following expression.
$$f(x,y) = d((x,y),(0,0))+ d((x,y),(1,0))+ d((x,y),(0,1))+d((x,y),(3,4))$$
[image]
The answer is: $5+\sqrt2$. In case of proof, we can plot it on the two-dimensional plane to use the inequality of triangle.
For any point $\color{purple}{P(x,y)}$ other than $(\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7})$,$$f(x,y)=\overline{\color{purple}{P}O}+\overline{\color{purple}{P}A}+\overline{\color{purple}{P}B}+\overline{\color{purple}{P}C}\\=\color{blue}{\underbrace{(\overline{\color{purple}{P}O}+\overline{\color{purple}{P}C})}_{two\,  side\, of\,\triangle O\color{purple}{P}C}}+\color{red}{\underbrace{(\overline{\color{purple}{P}A}+\overline{\color{purple}{P}B})}_{two\,  side\, of\,\triangle A\color{purple}{P}B}}\\>\overline{CO}+\overline{AB}\\=\overline{DO}+\overline{DC}+\overline{AD}+\overline{DB}\\=f(\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7})\\=5+\sqrt2$$

Comment: Can you explain why that would be minimum? Thank you!

Comment: Use inequality of triangle .

Comment: Thank you very much for such a nice explanation!

Answer (score 5):

That would be the intersection of the diagonals of $ABCD$ where $A(0,0),B(0,1),C(3,4),D(1,0)$ so it's point $(3/7,4/7)$ and $f(3/7,4/7)=\sqrt 2+5$

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell how did you conclude that the intersection of the diagonals would minimise the sum of distances from the four points?

Comment: Why intersection of diagonals (of an *irregular* quadrangle)?

Comment: @MaxPayne If M is the point you need, minimum of AM+CM is when M is on AC, and minimum of BM+DM is when M is on BD...

Comment: @MarianD Isn't this simple if the quadrilateral is irregular, try also to minimise sum of distances to a 3 points

Comment: I get it now!!!

Comment: @MaxPayne - Please, share it with us more stupid.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov - If I will know how to minimize this sum to 3 points, will it help me to minimize for 4 points? How?

Comment: @MarianD I don't think it will help, it's just a less complex problem

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov - You said "minimum of AM+CM is when M is on AC, and minimum of BM+DM is when M is on BD". It is of course true. But where is written that minimum of all 4 distances have be at the same time minimum of 2 of them?

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov - So you admit that it is only (no such bad) estimate?

Comment: @MarianD it accidently appeared that M(3/7,4/7) is one of the minimums of AM+CM and also one of the minimums of BM+DM, so is the minimum of AM+CM+BM+DM. So yes, pure luck to be able to solve this... Cheers

Comment: Oh, you are totally right, excuse me for my own stupidity. I now upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once you complete the squares and find that the four components are centered in
$$
\left( {0,0} \right),\left( {1,0} \right),\left( {0,1} \right),\left( {0,1} \right),\left( {3,4} \right)
$$
the next step is to realize that
$$
\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }  = r
$$
that is that the value of each component corresponds to 
the distance from the center point (they are vertical cones).
So the sum will be equal to the sum of the distances from the four points,
which is minimum at ...